# CSS Wrapping text around images

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, fluid

for this website I've been building I need to display the content a certain way, I have a thumbnail, two screenshots and a block of text about 500 words. I need to have the text wrapping around my thumbnail and screenshots. Currently I'm using PHP `substring` to break up the content of words and display them where I need it but this isn't working as text displays different on every browser I need a fluid solution, you can see an example of the page I'm talking about  [HERE](http://theapplist.com/index.php?art_id=0), I need the images to stay like that but the text to wrap around the images instead of having weird spacing where there should be more word. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: "weird spacing where there should be more word." that's the space because the whole next word  wont fit

Comment: @Dagon It looks like that because I use multiple `p` tags but is there a way to do the same with with 1 p tag so is wraps nicely, thanks!

Comment: Put `<p>` tags at paragraph boundaries, and put the images in the text more-or-less where they're supposed to go. You've currently got `<p>` tags just dropped in at apparently random places.  Just don't do that and things should work fine.

Comment: @Pointy, so simple thank you so much, I simply now have 1 `<p>` tag and then I split the content up with substr and placed the images where they should go, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Simply floating the images will do the trick. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/agrublev/a5RJN/

```
<img src="xx.jpg" style="float:left;">
```

Comment: Thanks, but they're already being floated I guess what I'm looking for is there a way to do the same thing but with just 1 `p` tag thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try giving align="left" to the image that will be contained in the p
If you want a margin it can look like this

```
<img src="#" align="left" style="margin-right:10px;">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the size (width, height) of the space where you want to put the words with a hole in it (the picture), you could generate an SVG. Advantages: it works in all the browser and you have the freedom of putting your words as you like (you can even rotate them).

And of course, you can use the generated SVG as a widget.

Answer (score -1):

I found a code example that might be of some use to you. Of course using the position attribute won't help as words won't wrap around it. But maybe wrapping the image in a div and using margin like so can help.

http://codepen.io/atomworks/pen/algcz